# analyize a variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I Have a script , which in middle of the code I need to analyze a variable, I am doing all this inside a long code. so for example my variable could be `variable=word1:word2` or `variable=word1` so I have 2 cases one is the variable consist of one word and the other I have 2 words separated by `:` 
now IF `variable=word1` then I dont want to do anything , but
IF `variable=word1:word2` THEN `SET variable=word1` and `SET variable2=word2`

by the way I dont know how long is the word1 or word2 so I cant just separate them by their position

Comment: Show us your code. And where your code fails?

Comment: my code dose not fail , it work , but I want to add this feature in it, you see that in my code when I print %variable% , will print word1:word2 , so I thought that maybe there is a way to separate them and make to variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need.

Just use `var1` and `var2` where you need them.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var=word1:word2
echo %var% | find ":" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
rem It does have 2 vars
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ("%var%") do set var1=%%a && set var2=%%b
echo !var1!
echo !var2!
) else (
rem Only 1 var
)
pause >nul
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. +1 for your question as well.

Comment: I have questions , can I use a word as a delimiter instead of `:` ? can I divide the variable into 3 words word1:word2:word3 ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use more than one char for delimiting, just try it and see. You can divide it into 3 if you want, just put `&& set var3=%%c` on the end of the `for` loop.